# My media query is not working when the touchscreen events button is activated

Tags: html, css

In the inspect menu when I choose the adaptive view and resize my screen everything works fine but when I click on the touchscreen events button my page change and doesn't fit like the viewport was not my actual screen.
That's the line if have in my header :

And that's the line I use for media query in css :

@media only screen and (max-width: ...px) {
...
}

Comment: `@media (orientation: portrait) {
  #id{ 
  }}`
Give inside this .. Also if you have given any css in index file , you should mention with !important property